# MySQL SELECT LIKE AND

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have the following error:
When i'm trying to select any name that matches the pattern from 'red' column, i get 0 which means that didn't match any number, but when i'm trying to select any name from 'blue' column, i get 1, which means success.
Can someone explain this to me please? 
I guess this is not a syntax error.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are comparing two columns to the string, you need to use the `LIKE` keyword twice:

```
SELECT...FROM...WHERE (red like '%foo% or blue like '%foo%') AND...
```